# Regex: How to strip email before "@" symbol?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have the following String

```
First Last <first.last@email.com>
```

I would like to extract

```
"first.last"
```

from the email string using regex & PHP. How to go about this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In looking at the answers, you may want to note that `"e\@w"@example.com` is, technically, a valid email address.

Comment: Just realized there was more to the string than just the email address.

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->beforeLast('@')`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L399) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know the answer was already accepted, but this will work on any valid email address in the format of: `Name <identifier@domain>`

```
// Yes this is a valid email address
$email = 'joey <"joe@work"@example.com>';

echo substr($email, strpos($email,"<")+1, strrpos($email, "@")-strpos($email,"<")-1);
// prints: "joe@work"
```

Most of the other posted solutions will fail on a number of valid email addresses.

Answer (score 6):

```
$str ="First Last <first.last@email.com>";
$s = explode("@",$str);
$t = explode("<",$s[0]);
print end($t);
```

Comment: Ghostdog, I like this solution too, but to be fair my question asked for a regex. But nonetheless your solution works great, thanks for your response!

Comment: Btw, what does print end() do?

Comment: fair enough. Its your choice. I just presented a simpler alternative, for your particular string sample. end($t) is the last element of the array. check the PHP docs for more

Answer (score 3):

This is a lot easier (after checking that the email IS valid):

```
$email = 'my.name@domain.com';
$split = explode('@',$email);
$name = $split[0];
echo "$name"; // would echo "my.name"
```

To check validity, you could do this:

```
function isEmail($email) {
    return (preg_match('/[\w\.\-]+@[\w\.\-]+\.\[w\.]/', $email));
}
if (isEmail($email)) { ... }
```

As for extracting the email out of `First Last <first.last@domain.com>`,

```
function returnEmail($contact) {
    preg_match('\b[\w\.\-]+@[\w\.\-]+\.\[w\.]\b', $contact, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just use a split function instead?  I don't use PHP but seems like this would be far simpler if it's available.

Answer (score 1):

If that's the *exact* format you'll get, then matching against the regex

```
/<([^@<>]+)@([^@<>]+)>/
```

will give you e.g. `first.last` in capture group 1 and `email.com` in capture group 2.

Comment: Note that this chokes on email addresses containing multiple @s. I doubt this is a problem for the vast majority of users though - and in this case, a solution which works 99.9% of the time takes less than 0.1% of the effort involved in getting the last 0.1% working correctly.

Comment: with /slightly/ more work, you can find the last @ in the string knowing that according to the RFC, the name is the portion before that final @.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use regexp; much more efficient to use some simple string functions.

```
$string = 'First Last <first.last@email.com>';
$name = trim(substr($string, 0, strpos($string, '<')));
```

Comment: Except you're getting "First Last" as your result, not "first.last"